# Are particles always represented by 4-volume preserving transformations?

Tags: spacetime, group-theory, representation-theory

I've been reading about affine gauge gravity, which uses the affine group A(4,R) (for example [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/037015739400111F)  ). If I'm getting it right there seems to be an “affine higgs” mechanism that breaks symmetry down to $SL(4,R)$, the half integer representations of which describe fermionic matter. I'm aware of a couple things that are true regardless of the theory we're looking at:

- The [Affine group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group)  $A(4,R)=Gl(4,R)\ltimes R^{1,3}$
  (for pseudo-Riemannian space).
- The [special affine group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Special_affine_group): $SA(4,R)=SL(4,R)\ltimes R^{1,3}$ of which $SL(2,C)\ltimes R^{1,3}$, the connected double cover of the Poincare group is at least a subgroup (isomorphic?).

Geometrically, I know the special affine group is exactly the set of transformations which preserve 4-volume. Thanks to Wigner, I also understand that (some of) the lattermost groups irreducible representations describe elementary particles.

I guess what I'm asking is whether there is something more geometrically fundamental going on.
Particle representations just happen to also be the set of transformations leaving 4-space with the same volume? I'm pretty new to all of this, so I'm wide open to nudges in various direction or books you think I ought to read.